# Measurement on two Qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, measurements

Assuming I have two Qubits, i.e. a four-dim. Hilbert space. In the following, I choose the basis {|11>,|10>,|01>,|00>}. I want to have a look on the non-diagonal part <11|$\rho$|00>. How can I measure this in experiment? In general I would say I have to use a representation of the $SU(4)$.
But somehow I have to get insight to this element by doing measurements on each of the Qubits?

Any ideas, papers or books to this topic?

Comment: This is called "quantum state tomography". Here's a [question and answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138765/how-do-we-perform-transverse-measurements-in-a-two-level-system) about how to measure qubits about an arbitrary axis. The two qubit cases is pretty much the same.

Comment: Thank you. This example was very helpful, but I'm still a bit confused how to do this in experiment, since the two Qubits are two physical seperated systems. I could use some kind of Hadamard gate on each of the Qubits and do a measurement then, but I'm still not sure how that would be related to the non-diagonal element of the two Qubits. Another question would be: If you have a Bell state (let's assume two two-level quantum system), how would you measure the coherence?

Comment: Hope my question is clear enough. (I am an undergraduate student, so it could be that many obvious things are not totally clear to me yet)

Comment: Have you looked up any of the original papers on "state tomography".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to apply [CNOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) gate, so you're then looking at $\langle01|\rho|00\rangle$ instead of $\langle11|\rho|00\rangle$. Then you can post-select on the first qubit being $|0\rangle$ (i.e. keep redoing the experiment and throwing out runs where the first qubit measures as $|1\rangle$) and go about measuring the off-diagonal term of the single remaining qubit.

You can measure the off-diagonal term of a single qubit by repeating your experiment a bunch of times, and measuring the output state along a bunch of differences axes. The axis where results deviate the most from 50/50 is probably the direction the spin is pointing along. Then you figure out how pure-vs-mixed the system is by measuring along that axis a lot.

**The naive method I just explained is not optimal. At all.** I just wanted to get across the general idea. For more information, read up on [quantum state tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography).

---

**If you can't perform non-local operations**, the task can still be done. But you'll need an EPR pair. Read [the paper 'Nonlocal Measurements via Quantum Erasure'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1575) (or [my blog post about it](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quantum/2016/03/01/paper-as-problem-nonlocal-measurements-via-quantum-erasure.html)), where they explain how circuits like this:

[image: Non-local measurement]

can perform non-local measurements, via the EPR pair, without needing to perform any non-local operations during the experiment.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you very much!!